# Can the Telepathy spell convey enough information to qualify a location for Clairvoyance or Scrying?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, telepathy

Clairvoyance and Scrying are both useful spell for seeing a specific location:

> You create an invisible sensor within range in a location familiar to you (a place you have visited or seen before) or in an obvious location that is unfamiliar to you (such as behind a door, around a corner, or in a grove of trees).

or

> you can choose a location you have seen before as the target of [*scrying*]. When you do, the sensor appears at that location and doesn't move.

If I want to create this sensor at a location I haven't seen before in person, can I gain enough knowledge through *telepathy* to do so? Keep in mind that *telepathy* can share images:

> Until the spell ends, you and the target can instantaneously share words, **images**, sounds, and other sensory messages with one another through the link...

...so I'm mostly wondering if images of a location are enough to qualify for *clairvoyance* and *scrying*'s "seen before" requirement.

Answer (score 3):

**As written, one works and one doesn't.**

*Clairvoyance* states:

> You create an Invisible sensor within range in a location familiar to you (**a place you have visited or seen before**)

This makes an obvious distinction between having visited a location and merely having seen it before, and both work. How can you see a place you haven't visited? Images, dreams, mystical visions all become valid ways to impart that information.

*Scrying* is a bit different and says:

> Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a location you have seen before as the target of this spell.

This leaves it up to interpretation as to what 'you have seen' before means. Taken alone, just from the description of the *Scrying* spell, the DM could rule either  you have to have been there or that viewing it via some others means is acceptable.
If you take the wording of *Clairvoyance* into account then 'seeing' is different from 'visiting' and still works.

Answer (score 0):

### No

(Other DMs may rule differently).

Both are explicit that you must have seen the location. Seeing an image of that location - whether through telepathy, by looking at a painting, or seeing it in a book - is not you seeing the location.

If it was, there would be no point to tourism.